# TS strictNullChecks false different behaviour in conditional type

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
interface BaseOptions {
  prefix?: string;
}

function foo<T extends BaseOptions>(options?: T): T['prefix'] extends string ? 1 : 2 {
  return 1 as any;
}
```

When using `strictNullChecks: true` I get the expected type result:

```
// strictNullChecks: true
const v1 = foo(); // 2
const v2 = foo({ prefix: 'bar' }) // 1
```

But when using `strictNullChecks: false` it's broken:

```
// strictNullChecks: false
const v12 = foo(); // 1
const v22 = foo({ prefix: 'bar' }) // 1
```

What's the reason for this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without strict null checks a type like `string` allows within it's definition the values `null` and `undefined`, so the type of the optional property will changed from `string | undefined` with strict null checks, to just `string` without that option (since `undefined` is just absorbed in to `string`).

This means that without strict null checks, `BaseOptions['prefix'] extends string` resolves to `string extends string` which is always true, while with strict null checks it resolves to `BaseOptions['prefix'] extends string` resolves to `string | undefined extends string` which is false.

You could use a default of `never` for the type parameter and test for `never` instead:

```
function foo<T extends BaseOptions = never>(options?: T): [T] extends [never] ? 2 : 1 {
  return 1 as any;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QPIAczAD2IGyA3gFDLK5QQzAAeA-AFzIZhSgDmA3BQC+FCjACuIBAWLIYhQgB4AKsgiNIIACal0WPNJLIAvMhAQAbtAB8ACkL4iJNsiUBKdgG0lAXVXqIWqQeZpZQvszIAEzI7ACM5FTIdGBiUCDI8ZjIcCAAngLCFAjEnMjm8SZyhDaufMgA9PVRRSVgZdGV8jZkNHQMjOwA5ABGcFCDyIKuDU2xIkA)

Or if you want to check specifically for the property, you could also use `keyof`:

```
function foo<T extends BaseOptions = never>(options?: T): keyof T extends 'prefix' ? 1 : 2 {
  return 1 as any;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QPIAczAD2IGyA3gFDLK5QQzAAeA-AFzIZhSgDmA3BQC+FCjACuIBAWLIYhQgB4AKsgiNIIACal0WPNJLIAvMhAQAbtAB8ACkL4iJNsiUBKdgGsIAT0IwXquoQWqQA5LT0TKHIzMgAjMjsAEzkVMh0YGJQIPHImHkg3gLCFAjEnMjmCSZyhDaufMgA9E3ISaXlYJUpNfI2ZDR0DIzsoQBGcFDRgq7NrXEdJF3mAMzGsn0DyDNz8SJAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do we need the array ([T])?

Comment: To avoid distribution over naked type parameters. `T extends never ? 2: 1` would get resolved to `never` if `T` is never, as distribution over the empty union (ie `never`) always results in `never`. If we put `[T]` we no longer have a naked type parameter and distribuition is no longer a factor. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types

Comment: Now I see that you didn't give a complete answer. In my example, I need to check whether the T['prefix'] extends string. In your answer, you check that whole options exist.

Comment: @undefined Ok. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @undefined Added another version that specifically checks for the presence of the property.